# In table, how to make one column has different font size for different line?

Tags: tables, fontsize, longtable

I use longtabu to create a table, below is the realted code

```
\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {|>{\footnotesize}X[1 , p ] |>{\footnotesize}X[1 , p ] | >{\footnotesize}X[1 , p ]|}
```

I want the first line of the table (table head) to be footnotesize, and I need one column with tiny font size, but if i change footnotesize to tiny, all lines in that column become tiny, the first line should be footnotesize. How to do it?

Comment: you can just start your heading cells with `\footnotesize`

Comment: Please always post the code for a complete, small document demonstrating your issue (Minimum Working Example). This is much more useful than mere fragments of code!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, THANKS! what a small change but big difference

Answer (score 2):

As noted in comments you can specify the default font for a column using the `>` syntax but override the font for heading or any other cells by starting the cell with a command such as `\footnotesize`.